# Thank for : Thank

Tags: transitivity

I had got one message from co-worker :

Thanks your support

But I had thought thank for your support is correct. So I had checked en.wiktionary.org and it doesn't have thank with a meaning of intransitive.

Which one is correct?

Comment: *Thank* is a transitive verb used as in *thank you*. Here the implied subject is *I*. *Thank* is a noun too, but it is used as a noun usually in plural form *thanks*. Many thanks, thanks a lot etc are examples. *Thanks your support* is not correct. It should have been *thanks for your support*.

Comment: @mahmud koya why? I need theoretical reason

Comment: Using *thanks* transitively applies the thanks to whoever supported you, either as an instruction to you (thank your support [for me]) or as a subtitle of sorts for their own actions ([he] thanks your support). On the other hand, "thanks *for* your support" expresses gratitude to you for the support you provided.

Answer (score 2):

@mahmudkoya is correct.  Let me build on his comment.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thank) defines "to thank" as:

> to express gratitude to • thanked her for the present—used in the phrase *thank you* usually without a subject to politely express gratitude.

In the phrase "thank you for your support" or "thanks for your support" the subject is identified by the function word "for."  In the case of your example, the subject of the sentence is "support."  Without the connecting word "for," the sentence is incomplete and difficult to read.  It's relevant [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for) is:

> used as a function word to indicate purpose • a grant for studying medicine

Therefore...

**Thanks your support** is incorrect.

**Thanks for your support** is correct.

Comment: Still vague. Which property of thank makes it incorrect? If not defini which factor you want to denote?

Comment: They could have said 'Thanks' on its own, or 'Thanks, Beverlie' but if you specify _for what_ you are thanking someone you need to include the word 'for'.